# How to Restore contacts taken from newer android version into PC and into old android version

Tags: samsung-galaxy-grand

How restore contacts from PC (back up took very long back from galaxy S3/S4 using samsung kies 3 or samsung smart switch and now phone not available) into Samsung  Grand Duos GT-I9082, 4.2 Jelly bean version. I do not have Memory card. When I try connecting Samsung Galaxy grand Kies 3 is showing message as 'Unsupported model or version'?

Comment: If you are using Gmail and sync enabled simply enable sync on new account. Don't need to use Kies

Comment: When i long back took backup to PC seems sync was not enabled to Gmail. I tried this as well  but now backup contacts are in PC which needs to be restored back into my Grand duos mobile.

Comment: Try an earlier version of Kies. Maybe that helps ?

Comment: I don't have. Try this method https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?s=0a9f6a4f5d3118fefcd50ba4ba85240f&p=16275621&postcount=5